# AngularFire Google OAuth not retrieving the user's email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to get the email address from Google OAuth using AngularFire, but on popup, it's not asking for the email permission.

This is the code from [Firebase Google auth doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html)

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) { /* Your Code */ }, {
  scope: "email"
});
```

It works in my angular application, but how can I fix my angular code to do the same?

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google").then(function(authData) {
   /* Code */
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
});
```

[Link to the same problem with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28612747/3927928), but I don't get the answer and how to fix it.

Comment: Also from the same doc, for reference: `authData.google.email` contains the Google user's primary email address as listed on their profile. Returned only if a valid email address is available, and the Google email permission was granted by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try passing in the options?

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("google", { scope: 'email' }).then(function(authData) {
   /* Code */
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
});
```

As noted by Kato, the docs provide that information as well: [link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-authwithoauthpopupprovider-options)

Comment: Seems like the right choice. Also noted in the [API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html).

Comment: Thanks @Kato I updated my answer to reflect the docs as well.